# Instead of .resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this jQuery code:

```
  $(window).resize(function() {         
if ($(window).width() <= 1250) {
  $('#topbar').css('position', 'static');
} else {
  $('#topbar').css('position', 'fixed');
}
});
```

Problem is, when you have zoomed in lesser than 1250 and then reload the page this jQuery doesn't work. So how do i fix this?

Comment: You should be using media queries for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to trigger resize handler maybe:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(this).width() <= 1250) {
        $('#topbar').css('position', 'static');
    } else {
        $('#topbar').css('position', 'fixed');
    }
}).triggerHandler('resize');
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks alot! Just have a questions, what does 'resize' in triggerHandler do?

Comment: "Description: Execute all handlers attached to an element for an event." http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/  But as Šime Vidas explained it, in CSS3 compliant browsers, this could be typically done using media queries

Comment: Since the jQuery code for .resize is larger then what i posted, im gonna avoid changing to @media for now. Thanks for the help both of you!

Answer (score 2):

Do this in CSS:

```
#topbar {
    position: static
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1250px) {
    #topbar {
        position: fixed
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/krrvA/show/ (I'm using background colors to indicate the toggle. Resize the window horizontally and the color will change at 1250px.)